# attempting to reload app on iPhone with expo but returns "ENOENT: no such file or directory" error. after adding png pics

Tags: json, react-native, expo

I am following a coding project from the book "Fullstack react-native" which is building a weather app in react-native. I added png pictures to the assets directory for a component that displays pictures on the app. And I am reloading the app using expo, but when expo attempts to build the Javascript bundle it throws the error "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/jliby/weatherios/utils/assets'
Failed building JavaScript bundle".

I have tried to  reset the cache and also checked the JSON paths.

app.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, Platform, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

import getImageForWeather from './utils/getImageForWeather'

import SearchInput from './components/SearchInput';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
        <ImageBackground 
          source={getImageForWeather('Clear')}
          style={styles.imageContainer}
          imageStyle={styles.image}>

        <Text style={[styles.largeText, styles.textStyle]}> San Francisco  </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.smallText, styles.textStyle]}>Light Cloud</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.largeText, styles.textStyle]}>24˚</Text>

        <SearchInput placeholder="Search any city" />
        </ImageBackground>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#34495E"
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex : 1
  },
  image: {
    flex :1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode:'cover',
  },
  blue: {
    color : 'light-blue',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  largeText: {
    fontSize : 40
  },
  smallText: {
    fontSize : 20
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    textStyle: Platform.select({
      ios: {
        fontFamily: 'AvernirNext-Regular'
      },
      android: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      },
     }),
    },
});
```

app.json

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "weatherios",
    "slug": "weatherios",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "jest-expo": "33.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Hey welcome to SO, could you please paste your code, not images of it.

Comment: Just to add on to what Madison said, this is the formatting guide, which you might find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: ok thank you for the advice